# How we can access the array objects of javascript passing through ajax in java?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring, dojo

I need to access array objects of javascript passed through ajax in java. I am using dojo.

This is how I tried to pass values through dojo ajax call.

**Javascript**

```
var arrayObj = [{'id': 4, 'label': 'first', 'value': 'success'}, {'id': 6, 'label': 'second', 'value': 'failed'}];

dojo.xhrPost({       
  url: "test/deleteItems.json",
  content: { items: arrayObj },
  handleAs: "json",
  load: function(response) {
    alert('got response');
  }
});
```

In Java(Spring MVC), I tried with `List of String`, `array of Strings` in `java controller` to access the `items` passed through Javascript Ajax. But none of them got worked with retrieving exact objects passed from Javascript.

**Java**

```
@RequestMapping(value="deleteItems", produces = "application/json")
     public @ResponseBody String deleteItems(
             @RequestParam(required = true) String[] items
             //@Valid @RequestBody List<AnalysisBean> pcptBean
             ) {
       /* I need to access the array objects passed from javascript here. */

}
```

How to retrieve the array objects in java controller?

**Note**: I tried with pass multidimensional array through Ajax to java controller.

```
var arrayObj = [[4,'first', 'success'],[6, 'second', 'failed']];
```

But it didn't work too.

I would like to get solution using Dojo/jQuery. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ObjectMapper` class from **Jackson** Library to parse your array of objects.
Here is the way you can do it:

> ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
>
> YourClass[] objects = mapper.readValue(items, YourClass.class);

BR.